# Understanding the PhD Applicant Selection Process in US Universities: Committee vs. Professor-Based?

Tags: phd, graduate-admissions, united-states

I'm interested in understanding more about how PhD applicants are selected in US universities. Specifically, I'm looking to find out whether a committee predominantly makes these decisions or if individual professors have a significant role in choosing their Ph.D. students.

Are there standard practices across most universities, or do they vary significantly from one institution to another? Additionally, how does the involvement of a committee or professors impact the selection criteria?